# How do I set a property of a subview?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UIView which I'm using as a container to display different subviews.

On the top level view controller, I am preparing the subviews like this:

subViewController, subView, and topView are properties of the top level view controller, so they shouldn't get deallocated.

```
subViewController = SubViewController()
subView = subViewController.view
subView.delegate = self // This is the part that doesn't seem to work
topView.addSubview(subView)
```

Then, I will display the subview by doing this

```
topView.bringSubviewToFront(subView)
```

I have a button in subView which is connected to an action like this

```
print("button pressed")
delegate?.click()
```

I am able to see the button and it prints when I press it. However, delegate is nil even though I thought I set it above. What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: The way it's being done above is correct. The issue was somewhere else.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that the `topViewController` which you set as `delegate` is not getting deallocated?

Comment: I think so. The top view controller is the controller that I made by dragging and dropping on the storyboard which is currently being displayed. I'm able to interact with the topView to change back and forth between sub views, so I don't think it's getting deallocated.

Comment: @abintom I just tried a test where I made a property with an initial integer value and tried to write to a different value the same way I was setting a delegate and it did not reflect the change when I printed it out. I think that somehow I'm not modifying the same copy of the subview that's actually being used?

Answer (score 0):

Move the `subViewController` declaration to outside the function scope so that the reference remains even after the scope of the function.

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {
    let subViewController = SubViewController()
    //...
}
```

Comment: I have the variable set as a property of the class, but initialized later

```subViewController: UIViewController!```

so it should remain.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing a subview's properties in the way that my question showed is correct. My issue was that I had two identical subviews and the one that I assumed would be on top was not on top. I had to explicitly call `bringSubviewToFront`.